# matplotlib pgf: OSError: No such file or directory in subprocess.py

Tags: matplotlib, latex, pgf

I try to use matplotlib to create a pgf file for LaTeX:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
from numpy import linspace
x = linspace(0, 100, 30)
fig, ax = subplots(figsize = (10, 6))
ax.scatter(x, x)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('/home/mark/dicp/python/figure.pgf')
```

But I get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visualize/latex_figs.py", line 32, in <module>
    fig.savefig('/home/mark/dicp/python/figure.pgf')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1957, in print_pgf
    return pgf.print_pgf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 818, in print_pgf
    self._print_pgf_to_fh(fh, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 797, in _print_pgf_to_fh
    RendererPgf(self.figure, fh),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 409, in __init__
    self.latexManager = LatexManagerFactory.get_latex_manager()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 223, in get_latex_manager
    new_inst = LatexManager()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 305, in __init__
    cwd=self.tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It also generates this part of the output file:

```
%% [whole bunch of comments]
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\begin{pgfpicture}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{10.000000in}{6.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{use as bounding box}%
```

I do not understand what `OSError: No such file or directory` in subprocesses.py has to do with anything... The file I'm trying to save is writable. Am I misunderstanding something, or is this a bug I should report?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also had this problem while trying to run the example scripts. The problem occurs where `backend_pgf.py` first tries to use the default LaTeX command. It seems that the PGF backend assumes that it should use `xelatex` by default. If the problem is the same for you as for me, then you have two options:

- add the key `"pgf.texsystem" : "pdflatex"` (or `lualatex`, whatever) to your `matplotlib.rcParams`. For example, add the following snippet to the top of your script:

  ```
  import matplotlib
  pgf_with_rc_fonts = {"pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex"}
  matplotlib.rcParams.update(pgf_with_rc_fonts)
  ```
- ensure that you have `xelatex`, and that it is on your `PATH`, and use that as the default latex command (i.e. assuming you're on a Mac or Linux system, `which xelatex` should return a path).

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much. I still had this problem with latest version of matplotlib (`1.4.3`)

Comment: Oneliner to fix for current user on linux(Mint 17.3, but should be general): `echo 'pgf.texsystem : pdflatex' >> ~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`